# Object in stack of `main` function is overwritten when first task runs (FreeRTOS)

Tags: c++, freertos

I try to explain my problem with a simple example

```
typedef function<bool()> TaskCallback;

class Task
{
public:
    Task(TaskCallback task_callback) : task_callback(task_callback)
    {
        long_string_test = "This is a long string 0123456789ABCDEF 0123456789ABCDEF 0123456789ABCDEF";

        xTaskCreate(Task::RunTask, "task_name", 2560, this, 3, &task_handle);
    }

    ~Task()
    {
        while(1); //Breakpoint: The destructor is never called
    }

private:
    static void RunTask(void* params)
    {
        Task* _this = static_cast<Task*>(params);

        _this->task_callback(); //The program crashes here because task_callback doesn't exist
    }

    string long_string_test;

    TaskCallback task_callback;

    TaskHandle_t task_handle;
};
```

main.cpp

```
static bool Init_task() { }

void main()
{
    Task task(Init_task);

    vTaskStartScheduler();

    //We should never get here as control is now taken by the FreeRTOS scheduler
    while(1);
}
```

If I check the value of the string `long_string_test` through the debbuger in the `RunTask` function I find that it has a strange value, as if the string had been destroyed.
But the destructor of `Task` class was never called.

If I change the "main.cpp" as below the program works correctly, I think the compiler does some sort of optimization:

```
static bool Init_task() { }

Task task(Init_task);

void main()
{
    vTaskStartScheduler();

    //We should never get here as control is now taken by the FreeRTOS scheduler
    while(1);
}
```

p.s. obviously compiler optimizations are disabled

Comment: What platform is this on? How is the scheduler implemented?

Comment: @Botje I'm programming on a system embedded (STM32F429ZI) with VisualGDB Toolchain (v5.5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As part of the `vTaskStartScheduler` call, `prvPortStartFirstTask` will [reset the stack pointer](https://github.com/rucek/stm32f4-freertos-starter/blob/master/src/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F/port.c#L282-L297). I can imagine that this will eventually cause other code to overwrite parts of the `Task` object on the discarded stack space allocated for `main`. You could set a data breakpoint with the debugger, but I would consider the `main` stack space trashed when the first task starts.

I think the best solution here is indeed to allocate the `Task` object statically or possibly with a heap allocation (if your system allows it).

Comment: You're right, I did some tests to verify what you said, see my next answer for more details.

Comment: Yes this is the key. In the section "How can I reduce the amount of RAM used?" on this page there is a description of what happens to the main stack space and it is not the same on all Ports.
https://www.freertos.org/FAQMem.html

Answer (score 1):

@Botje You're right I changed my example to verify what you said.

main.cpp

```
int* test;

static void RunTask(void* params)
{
    Print(*test);  //The "test" pointer has a random value
}

void main()
{
    int temp = 9999;

    test = &temp;

    xTaskCreate(RunTask, "task_name", 2560, NULL, 3, NULL);

    vTaskStartScheduler(); //It seems that FreeRTOS clears the main() stack

    //We should never get here as control is now taken by the FreeRTOS scheduler
    while(1);
}
```